# Does the inequality $x^2\leq x$ hold in Baer*-ring for $0 \leq x \leq 1$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, baer-rings

Let $A$ be a Baer*-ring and $x$ be a positive element with $0\leq x\leq1$ where $1$ is just the unit of $A$. Can we conclude $x^2\leq x$?

Comment: I looked up the definition of Baer ring and it did not seem to require an ordering, so are you considering a special type of Baer ring?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson With the involution * [Baer*, not just Baer], the positive cone consists of elements that can be expressed in the form, $\sum a_i a_i*$. The answer to the question is probably not, but I don't have a counter-example.

Comment: At first let us note that, we  focused on the Baer*-rings not Baer rings. In a Baer*-ring $A$, an element $a$ is called positive if there are $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ in $A$ with $a=\sum x^*_ix_i$. As  David Handelman determined just right now!

Comment: @David Handelman  I think so and it should be accrued in Baer *-rings in which positive elements have not necessarily  square root.